# Why is the Jetty version lower when using Maven?

Tags: maven

In my Maven setup, I have declared an artifact named A, which has a parent called A-root. Additionally, I have declared an artifact named B, which is referenced by A. Both A-root and B have separate declarations of the Jetty Bill of Materials (BOM). In B, the version of the jetty-http dependency is specified as 9.4.43.v20210629. In A-root, the version of the Jetty BOM is declared as 9.4.53.v20231009.

Furthermore, I have created a project named C that depends on A. When I execute the "mvn dependency:tree" command in the directory of A, the Jetty version displayed is 9.4.53.v20231009. However, when I execute the same command in the directory of project C, the Jetty version shown is 9.4.43.v20210629, which is a lower version. It seems that the Jetty BOM version declared in A-root's POM is not being applied correctly in project C.

```
    <groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>serviceA-root</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
  
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <jetty.version>9.4.53.v20231009</jetty.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
    </build>
```

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>demo</groupId>
        <artifactId>serviceA-root</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>serviceA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>serviceB</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
    </build>
```

```
<groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>serviceB</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <jetty.version>9.4.43.v20210629</jetty.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
          </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>    
          <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-bom</artifactId>
          <version>${jetty.version}</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies></dependencyManagement>
    <build>
    </build>
```

```
 <groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>serviceC</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>serviceA</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: higher version is effect only if i explicitly import  A-root for project C